# mysql Update in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to figure out how to update mysql table with array.

The table has 3 fields: id, rate, pol_id.
The "insert into" works perfect:

```
 foreach ($rates as $rn=>$rv) {
 $sql3=mysql_query("INSERT into `rates` (`rate`, `pol_id`) 
             values ( '$rv', '$polid',)") or die ("Unable to issue query sql2:   ".mysql_error()); }
```

$rates is actually array from dynamic input fields.

So I get something like this example:

```
id  |   rate |    pol_id
=========================
1   |   5.6  |     272  
2   |   6.3  |     272 
3   |   7.9  |     272
```

Now  I would like to edit the values in the input fields
 so I need to update the table:

I have tried this:

```
foreach ($rates as $rn=>$rv) {
$sql3=mysql_query("UPDATE `rates` SET `rate`='$rv' WHERE   `pol_id`='$polid'")or die ("Unable to issue query sql3: ".mysql_error()); }
```

But this isn't working, it updates all the rows with the last value.

Can ypu please help me with this?

Comment: you're not changing $polid in the loop, so you always use the SAME $polid.

Comment: But the $polid needs to stay the same. It's the foreign key from other table pol, which has  relation 1:n with rates table.

Comment: then instead of executing the queries, dump out the query strings - you'll probably find you're feeding in the data wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your $polid variable is not being changed inside the foreach loop. This causes your where statement to be **true** for all elements in the `rates` table that have the same pol_id (specified in $polid). This sets the value for 'all' entries (with pol_id = $polid) to the last value that you just entered (in $rv).

You could try adding a second condition to your where statement if you know the old value of rate to look like this:

```
$sql3=mysql_query("UPDATE `rates` SET `rate`='$rv' WHERE   `pol_id`='$polid' AND `rate`={old_value}")or die ("Unable to issue query sql3: ".mysql_error()); }
```

A nicer method is to use the id column of rates (as that is guaranteed to be unique) by first performing a query to retrieve the ID of the entry that you want and subsequently use that ID in the update query.

```
$query1 = mysql_query("select id from rates where {your desired condition};
/* Assign the result of $query1 to $id */
$sql3=mysql_query("UPDATE `rates` SET `rate`='$rv' WHERE   `pol_id`='$polid' AND `id` = $id)or die ("Unable to issue query sql3: ".mysql_error()); }
```

You can even let the `pol_id` = '$polid' out of the query now because of the id being unique.

Comment: Ok I am seeing more clear now. So I have changed little bit the database table. I have add new column rate_row where I save the key $rn. And then I update $sql3=mysql_query("UPDATE `policy_rates` SET `rate`='$rv' WHERE `policy_id`='$polid' AND `rate_row`='$rn'");

Comment: That sounds like a good solution, don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: +1 even if I think it would be better approach to try and get the `id`s of the rows to be updated and use something like `WHERE id=$id`. (This is necessary if `rate`+`pol_id` doesn't have unique index constraint. The original problem of updating multiple rows at once arises again.)

Comment: I definately agree but as @Lilou never mentioned or used the ids for rates in the original question I tried offering a option without them. I will edit my answer to include your suggestion however.

Comment: Yes, let this be a friendy warning to @Lilou and everyone else. You should always update a specific (unique) row or modify a specific (possibly non unique) value to something else. And **if you modify something based on non unique value you should be avare of it** or something goes horribly wrong eventually. You'll lose a track of modified rows and values quite quickly...

Comment: Thanks a lot Bas Jansen and ZZ-bb. I am very well aware of that. That's why I am testing many times before going on production.

Answer (score 1):

you are looping over $rates with the key $rn and the value $rv.

$polid stayes the same during the loop, so every update affects the same row/rows.